# Additional constraints during searching shortest path in weighted graph using NetworkX

Tags: graph, dijkstra, networkx

I've question to You about adding additional constraints during searching shortest path in weighted graph using NetworkX

Example graph:

```
G.add_edge(A, B, weight=1)
G.add_edge(B, C, weight=2)
G.add_edge(A, C, weight=1)
..
..
..
G.add_edge(Y, Z, weight=6)
```

So, now I want to find shortest path from A to F including some points eg: C, L, G, R (ordering has no meaning). How do that using NetworkX.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This probably isn't the best solution, but anyway:

```py
import networkx as nx
from string import letters
from random import sample, randint
from itertools import permutations

# generate random graph    
G = nx.Graph()

nodes = list(letters[:20])

for anode in nodes:
   G.add_node(anode, weight=randint(1,20))

for edge in [sample(nodes, 2) for i in range(60)]:
   G.add_edge(*edge)
```

Now, let's define our path-searching functionality:

```py
def multiple_dijkstra(G, apath, result, n=0, i=1):
   """For a path of: a - b - c - d, search recursively for the shortest
   paths between 'a' and 'b', then 'b' and 'c', then 'c' and 'd'.
   Return a list which is a path from 'a' to 'd' through 'b' and 'c'."""
   try:
      result.extend(nx.dijkstra_path(G, apath[n], apath[i])[:-1])
      multiple_dijkstra(G, apath, result, n+1, i+1)
      return result
   except IndexError:
      result.extend(nx.dijkstra_path(G, apath[n], apath[i-1]))
      return result

def possible_paths(start_node, end_node, *between):
   """Generate all possible paths based on permutations of *between"""
   for permutation in permutations(between, len(between)):
      yield [start_node] + list(permutation) + [end_node]

def gothrough_possible_paths(start_node, end_node, *between):
   """Test all permutations for shortest path"""
   for apath in possible_paths(start_node, end_node, *between):
      result = []
      shortest_path = multiple_dijkstra(G, apath, result)
      print 'Testing path: {}\nResult: {} (length: {})'.format(
                             ' - '.join(apath),
                             ' - '.join(shortest_path),
                             len(shortest_path))
```

Now, we can search for the shortest path:

```py
# let's pick 5 random nodes: a start node, end node and three in-between nodes
n1, n2, n3, n4, n5 = sample(nodes, 5)

# ...and search for the shortest paths between 'n1' and 'n2'
# such that 'n3', 'n4' and 'n5' are in-between nodes
gothrough_possible_paths(n1, n2, n3, n4, n5)
```

A possible results:

```py
Testing path: e - h - g - j - t
Result: e - k - h - k - g - k - b - j - b - t (length: 10)
Testing path: e - h - j - g - t
Result: e - k - h - k - b - j - o - c - g - k - b - t (length: 12)
Testing path: e - g - h - j - t
Result: e - k - g - k - h - k - b - j - b - t (length: 10)
Testing path: e - g - j - h - t
Result: e - k - g - k - b - j - b - k - h - l - t (length: 11)
Testing path: e - j - h - g - t
Result: e - j - b - k - h - k - g - k - b - t (length: 10)
Testing path: e - j - g - h - t
Result: e - j - o - c - g - k - h - l - t (length: 9)
```

So, the shortest path from `e` to `t` is through `j`, `g` and `h` (in this order), and the actual path is: `e - j - o - c - g - k - h - l - t`.

I am no expert on this, so I am curious of better solutions. Hope this helps, though.

Comment: Thank You. I think I found other solution.

1. Find all shortest paths between *specific* nodes.
2. Build second graph (only from *specific* nodes)
3. Solve TSP problem on second graph.

Comment: I'm using it to calculation of 30 nodes max., so the time is similar in both methods. The TSP solver (http://openopt.org/TSP) is faster while increasing the number of nodes. TSP has one more advantage -  I don't need to define target node.

Comment: @sAguinaga use ant colony optimization algorithm - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ant_colony_optimization_algorithms